# Insert or update in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails 4 app that I´m integrating with other system. Everyday we need to import their database. Some or most of the data should be already imported in our database (from previous loads).

When we try to insert an an existing object in the database, like this:

```
...
region = Region.new(id: id, name: name)
region.save
```

we get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique (Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY':
```

I thought save method creates in case the record doesn´t exist or update in case it exists. What am I missing? Should I find the object in the database first? Like:

```
region = Region.find(id)
if region
 #update fields
else 
 #create region
end
region.save
```

Is there a better, more effective, better performance (take into account there will be thousands of records) elegant Rails way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend to use `find_or_initialize_by` method:

```
region = Region.find_or_initialize_by(id: id)

// do stuff

region.save
```

How `find_or_initialize_by` works

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb, line 200
def find_or_initialize_by(attributes, &block)
  find_by(attributes) || new(attributes, &block)
end
```

---

Be careful because `find` method must find a record otherwise it throws an exception.

> Find by id - This can either be a specific id (1), a list of ids (1,
>   5, 6), or an array of ids ([5, 6, 10]). **If no record can be found for
>   all of the listed ids, then RecordNotFound will be raised**. If the
>   primary key is an integer, find by id coerces its arguments using
>   to_i.